# Remove elements from window based on Combobox selection xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following situation: inside xaml I get values from a database and fill the combobox..if the selected item in the combobox has a value "x" I want to hide some elements from the working window..thx for your tips

```
<TextBlock Text="XYZ:"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.KeyLists.XYZ, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
          SelectedValuePath="XYZId"  
          SelectedValue="{Binding XYZId, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this.

- you can make IValueConverter to convert selection values to Visibility, apply to each control with different converter parameter
- you can write styles with triggers for the convtols
- you could (not recommended) handle this in code

Comment: wich one is easier to implement? IValueConverter or styles with trigger?